# Establish KVM bridge with static IP

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, static-ip

I would like to establish a virtual machine (KVM) on Ubuntu Server and configure bridge networking in order to connect to the VM via static IP. I want to connect to the VM directly via SSH (bypassing the host).

However I have only remote access to the server (in case of emergency I have to get to the other end of the city) so I would like to avoid any issues which could cause losing network connection. The server is connected to the network which uses MAC filtering. Therefore the `/etc/netplan/config.yaml` looks like:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      dhcp4: true
    eth2:
      dhcp4: true
    eth33:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
```

And the `/etc/network/interfaces` file is empty. The IP address assigned to the server is e.g. 11.22.3.1 (`eth1`) and I have obtained additional static IP from network admin to create VM bridge which is 11.22.3.2
Now, which file should I edit (`/etc/netplan/config.yaml` or `/etc/network/interfaces`) and how it should look like afterwards? I have seen some guides to edit `eth1` by adding 'bridges' lines to `/etc/netplan/config.yaml`. If so, should I turn dhcp4: false and assign static 11.22.3.1 IP in the file? What would be the best solution of the issue?

Comment: You should have a plan B in case of network connectivity loss. Typically a remote console. Beside this, you should also describe how the host's provider's MAC address filtering works. Usually MAC filtering is incompatible with the use of a bridge. You still have left routing/ARP proxy, or ipvlan/ipvtap as workaround.